# Vue: Can I use a component filter inside a computed property?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

In a SFC I have

```
  filters: {
    localizedData: function () {
      return new Date(value).toLocaleString();
    }
  }
```

and

```
  computed: {
    todos() {
      return _.map(this.raw_todos, item => {
        return { 
          ...item.node,
          localizedData: this.$filters.localizedData(item.node.giorno)
        }
      });
    }
  },
```

The part not working is

```
this.$filters
```

because it's undefined. `this` is the Vue instance, but it has not the $filters... also I tried

```
   this.localizeData(..)
```

but `.localizeData` is not a function

What am I doing wrong and why?

Comment: Filters are really meant to be used in template. I think you are better off just making a method with same functionality.

Comment: `this.$options.filters`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like @Eric Guan said, filter is in `this.$options.filters`

You can refer to this https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-vue-filter-in-vm-instance

[image]